# Docusign Embedded Signing returnUrl issue

Tags: redirect, docusignapi

I am displaying an Embedded Signing view in an iFrame. I am able to get the embedded signing view to display correctly using templates. I am calling an internal service (server-side) from the client (browser) and the internal service calls the Post Recipient View endpoint in the Docusign API.

In order to redirect the user to the correct view in my web app after the Signing view redirects to the returnUrl, I need to have query string parameters on the returnUrl. Here is an example of the returnUrl:

```
{
  ...
  "returnUrl": "http://localhost:5000/#/my/path/redirect?sname=MY_VALUE&debug=foo,baz"
}
```

I am using the `sname` query parameter to hold the value for a string I will use to route to a view once the user is redirected from the Docusign Signing view.

**The Problem:**
When the iframe is redirected to the returnUrl after the Signing view is complete, the query string in the returnUrl is cutoff and the url of the iframe is:

`http://localhost:5000/#/my/path/redirect?sname`

when it should be

`http://localhost:5000/#/my/path/redirect?sname=MY_VALUE&debug=foo,baz`

I also read in the api documentation that an `event` parameter should also be present in the query string when redirecting, but that is not there either.

Is there a step that I am missing or is this a bug in the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a few tests using Postman and the resulting returnUrl is working for me. I even tried using yours directly (even though I obviously won't be able to connect to it) and it came up correctly as

```
http://localhost:5000/#/my/path/redirect?sname=MY_VALUE&debug=foo,baz&event=signing_complete
```

I even tried using an iframe for the signing session like you, still seems to be using the right URL when it redirects. So I've not been able to replicate your problem.

Are you attempting this in the demo environment?

Comment: Yes, this is currently hitting the Docusign demo api/environment while we are in development.

Comment: Also, is there an api call that will return the returnUrl that Docusign will use to redirect after the signing is complete? I can use this to see how Docusign is storing the returnUrl. That will help me to eliminate if the returnUrl is getting cut off before being persisted in the Docusign demo environment. I have ensured that the returnUrl is being sent to the Docusign api as intended.

Comment: No way to query the returnURL via the API. Can you share a few sample envelopeID's?

Comment: @jenny and Luis Scott Issue was caused after the returnUrl was returned to our application. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your thorough and timely response!